# How to specify Python version and library versions for PyInstaller executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable, libraries, interpreter

When creating an executable file using PyInstaller, how can I bundle a specific Python interpreter and some library from specific versions?

I want to create an executable file from my .py script. My `__main__.py` downloads some data from a website and transform them, then saves them in a folder as excel files.

And here are requirements.

1. Use Python 3.6

For this, I found [some related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443088/how-to-change-python-version-for-use-with-pyinstaller) but never clear to me. My **main**.py needs Python3.6 to be executed, and the users of this .exe file won't necessarily have Python3.6, so I want to bundle this Python in the .exe file as well. But is just a single command `python3 -m pyinstaller __main__.py` really enough? I'm not confident and I want to know what exactly I need to do.

2. Use specific versions of libraries such as pandas==0.23, beautifulsoup4==4.9.1 etc.

I think I need to work with `pure` in `.spec` file as [the documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html) says "pure: pure python modules needed by the scripts". But I cannot find any documentation about what exactly I need to do make it include pandas==0.23, beautifulsoup4==4.9.1 etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this using virtual environments: if you have an environment with the desired Python version and package versions, you can `pip` install PyInstaller there and build the .EXE from that environment.

The Conda version would be:

1. Create the environment:

```
conda create --name my_env_name python=3.6
```

2. Activate it:

```
conda activate my_env_name
```

3. Install your desired package versions and PyInstaller:

```
pip install pandas==0.23
pip install beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
pip install pyinstaller

# or to get the developer version, which fixes some issues I have run into
# pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```

4. And then build your EXE:

```
python pyinstaller myscript.py
```

Having this virtual environment can be a nice control as well for writing/testing your program, as it ensures no other dependencies are needed.  Because of this, I tend to only install the necessary packages for the script into the environment.

However, I am not sure how one would do this with `venv`, if you do not have Anaconda.  But maybe this will still point you in a direction (or someone else can elaborate? also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48662686/13386979)).

Comment: I had anaconda so it helped me a lot. thank you for your answer.