# Python - specify what library version to use (for all of them)

Tags: python, libraries, dependency-management

How to list in Python project all libraries and their version?
(similar to Java maven `pom.xml` and Node.js npm 'package.json')

There is [definitely way to specify that on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63494904/how-to-specify-python-version-and-library-versions-for-pyinstaller-executable),
e.g. `pip install pandas==0.23`, but that only hopefully will be listed in README, but most likely be forgotten.

Also as there is `pip` and `conda`, do they address this? Or maybe some other 3rd tool tries to unify for whatever pip or conda usage?

Comment: Do you want something more than `pip list` or `conda list`?

Comment: Depending on what exactly you need to do, ``requirements.txt``, ``setup.py`` or ``pyproject.toml`` should apply. Do you have a proper python package (which can be ``pip``-installed) and want to set its dependencies? Do you have a collection of python code and want to make the dependencies installable in one go?

Comment: Are requirements.txt, setup.py or pyproject.toml 3 different option/tools?
Please add answer with some direct links.  I am coming from Java, and in Java it is common to specify exact dependencies, so other developers can join development any install quickly all required dependencies (libraries) automatically. But in Python it seem brittle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [two main mechanisms](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/#install-requires-vs-requirements-files) to specify libraries for a package/repository:

- For an out-of-the-box package that can be installed with all dependencies, use [`setup.py`/`pyproject.toml`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#install-requires). These are used by package managers to *automatically* install required dependencies on package installation.
- For a reproducible installation of a given setup of possibly many packages, use [`requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files). These are used by package managers to *explicitly* install required dependencies.

Notably, the two handle different use-cases: Package dependencies define the *general* dependencies, only restricting dependency versions to specific ranges when needed for compatibility. Requirements define the *precise* dependencies, restricting all direct and indirect dependency versions to replicate some pre-existing setup.

Comment: thanks, I guess there is no options other than these.