# How can I make pyinstall use a specific version of a module

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an executable through pyinstall that requires the version 1.2.2 of the module playsound, how can I make it so it installs that version, and not the newest one, when creating the executable?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-version-with-pip) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63494904/how-to-specify-python-version-and-library-versions-for-pyinstaller-executable) should help you with what you want when looking for a specific version of a module.

Comment: I think Pyinstaller get version which you have installed - so you can reinstall expected version `pip install -U playsound==1.2.2` or you should use `venv` to create environment in which you will install `1.2.2` and run Pyinstaller.